# Prove $R$ is an order relation

Tags: relations

In $\mathbb{R^2}$  we consider the relation

\begin{equation}
(x,y)R(a,b)\Longleftrightarrow  (x=a \,\text{and} \, y=b)\, \text{or}\,(x^2+y^2<a^2+b^2)
\end{equation}

$R$ is an order relation if it is:

**1) Reflexive:** $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}, (x,y)R(x,y)$:

It's true because   $x=x$ and $y=y$

**2) Antisymmetric** $(x,y)R(a,b) $ and $ (a,b)R(x,y)\Rightarrow \, (x,y)=(a,b)$

It's true because if $x^2+y^2<a^2+b^2$ and $a^2+b^2<x^2+y^2$ then $x=a$ and $y=b$

**3) Transitive** $(x,y)R(a,b) $ and  $(a,b)R(c,d) $

It's true because: $x^2+y^2<a^2+b^2 $ and $a^2+b^2<c^2+d^2$ then $x^2+y^2<c^2+d^2$

So $R$
 is an order relation.

**Is correct my work?**

Comment: Your reasoning in 2) is false. For $x = a$ and $y = b$ we don't have $x^2 + y^2 < a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz The order isn't supposed to be strict - see the definition.

Comment: I missed seeing the "$(x=a~\text{and}~y=b)$ or" part.  That being said, this is missing from OP's attempts at proof for $2$ and $3$ as well.

Comment: @StefanMesken so how can I prove the antisymmetric?

Comment: You didn't start with the correct order. $(x,y)R(a,b)$ does not mean that $x^2 + y^2 < a^2 + b^2$. There is another possibility included in the definition of $R$ and that one leads to antisymmetrie.

Comment: @StefanMesken  By definition $x=a $ and $b=y$ then $(x,y)=(a,b)$ ??

Comment: No, that's not the correct order either. You have $(a,b)R(x,y)$ and thus [$a=x$ and $b=y$] or [$a^2+b^2 < x^2 + y^2$]. Similarly for $(x,y)R(a,b)$. Your proof already shows that the second part of this disjunction can't hold. Thus we may conclude that...?